# Python 2.7: Passing class methods to another function

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I have created a parent Class (Geometry) and Sub-Class (Point) with several methods. I am trying to use the methods in the two classes to run processes in the test function. I am having a hard time access those methods within a function.  I have created three points in the test function, P1 = (0,3), P2 = (-3,7), and P3 = (-3,7), and want to perform task on them. For instance, def **init**(self, x, y): is suppose to return the x,y coordinate of a point listed in the test function. I tried all of the following: print(test(Point(p1))), print test(p1.Point), and print p1.Point. None of them worked. Could someone please provide guidance on how I can execute that?

My code:

```
class Geometry(object):
    uniqueID = -1
    def __init__(self):
    Geometry.uniqueID += 1
    self.id = Geometry.uniqueID

class Point(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Geometry.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%.2f, %.2f)' % (int(self.x*100)/100.0, int(self.y*100)/100.0)


    def __eq__(self, point):
        if type(point) is Point:
            if self.x == point.x and self.y == point.y:
            return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            raise Exception("The input parameter has to be a Point object!")

    def identify(self, other):
        if type(other) is Point:
            if self.id == other.id:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            raise Exception("The input parameter has to be a Point object!")

    def distance(self, other):
        if type(other) is Point:
            x_square = (other.x - self.x) ** 2
            y_square = (other.y - self.y) ** 2
            d = (x_square + y_square) ** 0.5
            return float(d)
        else:
            raise Exception("The input parameter has to be a Point object!")

    def quadrant(self):
        output = ""
        if self.x > 0 and self.y > 0:
            output = "Quad I"
        elif self.x < 0 and self.y > 0:
            output = "Quad II"
        elif self.x < 0 and self.y < 0:
            output = "Quad III"
        elif self.x > 0 and self.y < 0:
            output = "Quad IV"
        elif self.x == 0:
            output = "Y-axis"
        elif self.y == 0:
            output = "X-axis"
        elif self.x == 0 and self.y == 0:
            output = "Origin"

        return output

def test(p1,p2,p3):
    p1 = Point(0, 3)
    p2 = Point(-3, 7)
    p3 = Point(-3, 7)



def collinear(p1, p2, p3):
    p1x = p1.x
    p1y = p1.y

# m1 = ?
# m2 = ?


def main():
    print (p1.Point)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the __ str __  implementation you have , I'm guessing you want to explicitly display the co-ordinates when printing an object. In that case, I was able to import your code and find out that your print logic works well.

Below is the working code:

```
class Geometry(object):
    uniqueID = -1
    def __init__(self):
        Geometry.uniqueID += 1
        self.id = Geometry.uniqueID

class Point(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Geometry.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%.2f, %.2f)' % (int(self.x*100)/100.0, int(self.y*100)/100.0)


    def __eq__(self, point):
        if type(point) is Point:
            if self.x == point.x and self.y == point.y:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            raise Exception("The input parameter has to be a Point object!")

    def identify(self, other):
        if type(other) is Point:
            if self.id == other.id:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            raise Exception("The input parameter has to be a Point object!")

    def distance(self, other):
        if type(other) is Point:
            x_square = (other.x - self.x) ** 2
            y_square = (other.y - self.y) ** 2
            d = (x_square + y_square) ** 0.5
            return float(d)
        else:
            raise Exception("The input parameter has to be a Point object!")

    def quadrant(self):
        output = ""
        if self.x > 0 and self.y > 0:
            output = "Quad I"
        elif self.x < 0 and self.y > 0:
            output = "Quad II"
        elif self.x < 0 and self.y < 0:
            output = "Quad III"
        elif self.x > 0 and self.y < 0:
            output = "Quad IV"
        elif self.x == 0:
            output = "Y-axis"
        elif self.y == 0:
            output = "X-axis"
        elif self.x == 0 and self.y == 0:
            output = "Origin"

        return output

def test():

    p1 = Point(0, 3)
    p2 = Point(-3, 7)
    p3 = Point(-3, 7)

    return p1, p2, p3




def collinear(p1, p2, p3):
    p1x = p1.x
    p1y = p1.y

# m1 = ?
# m2 = ?


if __name__ == "__main__":

    p1, p2, p3= test()

    #Either this 
    print "p1 is " + p1.__str__()
    print "p2 is " + p2.__str__()
    print "p3 is " + p3.__str__()

    print "\n*******************\n"

    #Or this
    print p1
    print p2
    print p3
```

Can you verify. Also  can you make sure if the Point(0.3, 0.4) is local to the function where you are actually doing a print.

Sample output for the above:

```
p1 is (0.00, 3.00)
p2 is (-3.00, 7.00)
p3 is (-3.00, 7.00)

*******************

(0.00, 3.00)
(-3.00, 7.00)
(-3.00, 7.00)
```

Comment: So the p1 coordinates have to be listed in the main function? I was trying to create a test function with three points listed under that function, P1 = (0,3), P2 = (-3,7), and P3 = (-3,7), and print those coordinates using the main function. I want my output to return  Coordinates = (0, 3)

Comment: so p1, p2 and p3 have a scope local to function test()  implying that  a function like main() doesn't know  what p1 , p2,p3 values are.  I've edited my solution.

Comment: can you check again !  I just made my edit the last minute , so  im guessing it takes some time to be consistent across the stack overflow servers